# How to estimate time to reach X with an exponentially increasing growth rate

Tags: calculus

I need to estimate the amount of time it will take to reach a desired number of `X`, when it's growth rate is constantly increasing (exponentially?).

## Example

In this example, there are 4 layers, with each layer from bottom to top feeding into the layer above it at a constant time interval, and finally the top layer which produces the final output `X`.

```
A: producing A of X every 1 second
B: producing B of A every 2 seconds
C: producing C of B every 3 seconds
D: producing D of C every 4 seconds
```

With this, we know that `C` is increasing at a rate of `D` every 4 seconds, `B` is increasing at a rate of `C` every 3 seconds, and so on up the chain to produce the final output of `A` of `X` every 1 second.

## Goal

Let's say I currently have `1,000 X` and our goal is to reach `10,000 X`. How can I estimate the amount of time `t` it will take to reach `10,000 X` with an arbitrary number of layers feeding into each other?

I need the final equation to be able to work with any number of layers and variances in each layer's individual time interval. I only included 4 layers and easy output numbers for the purpose of a simple example.

## Descriptive Example

For better demonstration purposes, a more specific example with exact outputs from zero to 4 seconds below.

```
Initial state (0 seconds):

X: 0
A (100): producing 100 of X every 1 second
B (50): producing 50 of A every 2 seconds
C (25): producing 25 of B every 3 seconds
D (10): producing 10 of C every 4 seconds

After 1 second:

X: 100 (+100)
A (100): producing 100 of X every 1 second (produced 100 X)
B (50): producing 50 of A every 2 seconds
C (25): producing 25 of B every 3 seconds
D (10): producing 10 of C every 4 seconds

After 2 seconds:

X: 250
A (150): producing 150 of X every 1 second (produced 150 X)
B (50): producing 50 of A every 2 seconds (produced 50 A)
C (25): producing 25 of B every 3 seconds
D (10): producing 10 of C every 4 seconds

After 3 seconds:

X: 400
A (150): producing 150 of X every 1 second (produced 150 X)
B (75): producing 75 of A every 2 seconds
C (25): producing 25 of B every 3 seconds (produced 25 B)
D (10): producing 10 of C every 4 seconds

After 4 seconds:

X: 625
A (225): producing 225 of X every 1 second (produced 225 X)
B (75): producing 75 of A every 2 seconds (produced 75 A)
C (35): producing 35 of B every 3 seconds
D (10): producing 10 of C every 4 seconds (produced 10 C)
```

Comment: If you look at the system each 12s what happens?

Comment: @LucasResende In my example, I used random numbers and only 4 layers. In reality, I need the final equation to be able to work with any number of layers and variances in each layers individual time interval. Will update my question to clarify this.

Comment: How the order preference works, if it is time do update A and X, we first update A and then X (with the new A)?

Comment: @LucasResende For the purpose of this example, yes, output priority is given to the deeper layers (D, then C, then B, then A). But in reality, time intervals will be fairly different and the chances of two outputting at the same exact time are very low in my real world use case. For example, one would be 32.92s and another would be 12.39s.

Comment: You want a closed formula? Why not just run the algorithm?

Comment: I need to be able to consistently calculate the time it will take to reach a specific goal under the current set of conditions which may change, triggering a recalculation of the estimated time. For example, I have `1,000 X` and `20 D` and some other combination of `A - C`, how long will it take to reach `10,000 X` versus when I have `50 D` and some combination of `A - C`

Comment: I don't think a closed formula is easy to reach, but since $X$ grows exponentially, the time so simulate the system until it reaches a desired $X$ will be so low that seems the best option. And probabily easier to code.

Answer (score 1):

You can just follow up the chain.  Each thing you start with generates $X$ in a given pattern.  The situation is linear, so you can just add things up.  The number of $D$ never changes, so $D(t)=D(0)$.  Since each $D$ makes a $C$ after $4$ seconds, it makes $\lfloor \frac t4\rfloor \ C's$ after $t$ seconds and $C(t)=\lfloor \frac t4\rfloor D(0)$ because we will count the $C'$s that were at the start later.  All those $C$'s make $B$'s after $3$ seconds, so $B(t)=B(t-1)+C(t-3)=B(t-1)+\lfloor \frac {t-3}4\rfloor D(0)$.  That equation hides the fact that the number of $B$'s is quadratically increasing in time because the second term is linearly increasing in time.  Then we have $A(t)=A(t-1)+B(t-2)=A(t-1)+B(t-3)+\lfloor \frac{t-5}4\rfloor D(0)$  Now it is the $B(t-3)$ term that makes $A(t)$ cubic in $t$.  Finally, $X(t)=X(t-1)+A(t-1)=X(t-1)+A(t-2)+B(t-3)$ is quartic in $t$.